# ImpressPages - Unable to add plugin / themes

Tags: impresspages

I am new to Impress Pages. Using version 4.2.7 ( Installed 4.2.6  and upgraded from within the CMS). I have the following issues;

1. Tried to add the "PHP" plugin and got error message

> "Plugin signature verification failed" . Plugin is NOT ADDED

2. I tried to add a new theme and got the error message `Unknown error. Please see logs.`
   Where are these logs ? I have tried `/var/log/apache2/error_log` , etc.

Update 1: The log within the cms shows ;

> 2014-11-01 17:00:44   Cron.finished   array(0) { } 2014-11-01 17:00:44
>     Cron.started    array(7) { 'firstTimeThisYear' => bool(false)
>   'firstTimeThisMonth' => bool(false) 'firstTimeThisWeek' => bool(false)
>   'firstTimeThisDay' => bool(false) 'firstTimeThisHour' => bool(true)
>   'lastTime' => int(1414828943) 'test' => NULL }

I dont see anything related to plugins or themes ? Is there another log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that the signature of the file can't be verified. There may be two reasons for that:

1. Your server is missing some encryption lib. But I guess current implementation should not require any additional libs.
2. The downloaded file is not what had to be downloaded. That could be due to DNS errors, network error, etc.

Which case it is can be told only by debugging. You can always download plugins from market.impresspages.org and install them manually.

If you want to debug, first place to look at is file/secure/tmp dir. You should find the downloaded plugin there. Have a look if you can unzip it. If you can un-zip, you have the problem number 1, otherwise 2.

Most likely your server couldn't download files from Internet.

You can

Comment: Thanx. Will try out your suggestions.

Comment: I located the plugin and theme under /webroot/file/secure/tmp/dir and unzipped them into the plugin and themes subdirectory. I then activated them through the system. It worked ! Thanx.

Comment: Could you tell me what encryption library i am missing? i have php5-mcrypt installed ?

Comment: I don't know what's missing on your server. The line that throws an error is Ip/Internal/Plugins/PluginDownloader.php line 53. That bit needs some debugging to find out the reason.

Comment: this problem still persists in ImpressPages 4.6.6 ?